# wp_remote_get() never fires

Tags: wp-remote-get

I am quite familiar with the `wp_remote_get()` function.  However, this one is blowing my mind.

Here is my code to call the url:

```
// data to send in our API request
        $api_params = array( 
            'edd_action'        => 'activate_license',               // Action -> Activate License
            'license'           => urlencode($license),              // License submitted by user
            'email'             => urlencode($email),                // Email submitted by user
            'transid'           => urlencode($transid),              // Transaction ID submitted by user
            'user_ip'           => urlencode($user_ip),              // IP submitted by hidden field
            'user_email'        => urlencode($user_email),           // Admin - Email
            'user_firstname'    => urlencode($user_firstname),       // Admin - First name
            'user_lastname'     => urlencode($user_lastname),        // Admin - Last name
            'user_url'          => urlencode($user_url),             // Admin - URL
            'user_admin_email'  => urlencode($user_admin_email),     // Admin - Email
            'timeout'           => 10                               // Set timeout to ensure all data passes successfully
            //'item_name' => urlencode( 'ultimate-tinymce-pro' )
        );

        // Call the custom API.
        $response = wp_remote_get( add_query_arg( $api_params, 'http://EXAMPLE.com/plugin_activate_membership.php' ) );
        // make sure the response came back okay
        if ( is_wp_error( $response ) )
            return false;

        // decode the license data
        $license_data = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ) );
```

The `$api_params` variables are all defined before this snippet.

I then process the `$license_data` from the returned code; after this snippet.

This all works 99% of the time; across multiple servers.

However, I have just encountered a site where the `wp_remote_get()` never fires.  The code stops at `if (is_wp_error ($response)) return false;`.

I can verify it is failing by sending an email to myself, within the error function.  However, I cannot get any info returned.

In Firebug, the function never fires.  It never even attempts the get request.  In all other sites, I can see in Firebug where the request is made.. and the response is given.

In this particular site... Firebug shows nothing.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I was able to receive an error by emailing myself during the check (it's performed on the `admin_init` hook).

Here is the code I had to use to get the error:

```
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $to      = 'example@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = $response->get_error_message();
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    return $response;
}
```

The result in my email:

```
couldn't connect to host
```

I'm now leaning towards a server setting.  Perhaps blocking outgoing TCP connections??

Comment: Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Comment: what's the error message? check it with for example: `echo $response->get_error_message(); ` within the `is_wp_error( $response )` part

Comment: Thanks guys.  That is what is weird.  Absolutely no error or debugging information.  Firebug never fires the function.. so I can never see the usual 'get' process.  It's as if the function doesn't exist.. therefore never executed.  No error response codes, etc.  Is it possible their server is preventing `wp_remote_get()` without returning any debug info?

Comment: Did you figure this out?